# Need a way to access control in a window with control id using pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

By using class name, value of control is retrieved from window using pywinauto functions. Recently this seems to be problem when trying to use for SAP because class name are dynamic. Is there a way to get dynamic class name of a control or is there way to access control using control ID instead of class name.

```html
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application().Connect(title=u'Create Purchase Order', class_name='SAP_FRONTEND_SESSION')
sapfrontendsession = app.SAP_FRONTEND_SESSION
print sapfrontendsession.PrintControlIdentifiers()

it gives

Control Identifiers:
Afx:62F20000:0:00010003:00000010:00000000 - ''   (L14, T38, R1352, B69)
 '' '0' '1' 'Afx:62F20000:0:00010003:00000010:00000000' ()
ComboBox - ''   (L54, T43, R196, B65)
 '2' 'ComboBox' ()
Edit - ''   (L57, T46, R174, B62)
 '3' 'Edit' ()
AfxWnd110 - ''   (L14, T69, R1352, B78)
 '6' 'AfxWnd1103' ()
AfxWnd110 - ''   (L65, T78, R1352, B109)
 '7' 'AfxWnd1104' ()
Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000000:00000000 - ''   (L14, T109, R1352, B143)
 '8' 'Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000000:00000000' ()
Button - ''   (L24, T115, R170, B135)
 '9' 'Button' 'Button0' 'Button1' ()
Button - ''   (L174, T115, R180, B135)
 '10' 'Button2' ()
Button - ''   (L184, T115, R204, B135)
 '11' 'Button3' ()
Button - ''   (L208, T115, R228, B135)
 '12' 'Button4' ()
Button - ''   (L232, T115, R270, B135)
 '13' 'Button5' ()
Button - ''   (L274, T115, R294, B135)
 '14' 'Button6' ()
Button - ''   (L298, T115, R304, B135)
 '15' 'Button7' ()
Button - ''   (L308, T115, R414, B135)
 '16' 'Button8' ()
Button - ''   (L418, T115, R483, B135)
 '17' 'Button9' ()
Button - ''   (L487, T115, R507, B135)
 '18' 'Button10' ()
Button - ''   (L511, T115, R634, B135)
 '19' 'Button11' ()
Button - ''   (L638, T115, R644, B135)
 '20' 'Button12' ()
Button - ''   (L648, T115, R761, B135)
 '21' 'Button13' ()
Button - ''   (L765, T115, R890, B135)
 '22' 'Button14' ()
Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000 - 'Standard PO created under the number 4500018380'   (L14, T699, R1352, B728)
 'Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000' 'Standard PO created under the number 4500018380' 'Standard PO created under the number 4500018380Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000' ()
Afx:62F20000:1008 - ''   (L14, T143, R1352, B699)
 '27' 'Afx:62F20000:1008' ()
Custom Container Class - 'Custom  Container'   (L17, T151, R44, B172)
 'Custom  Container4' 'Custom  ContainerCustom Container Class4' 'Custom Container Class4' ()
Shell Window Class - 'Control  Container'   (L17, T151, R44, B172)
 'Control  Container4' 'Control  ContainerShell Window Class4' 'Shell Window Class4' ()
SAPImage - ''   (L17, T151, R44, B172)
 '34' 'SAPImage2' ()
GOSContainer Class - 'Gos Container'   (L14, T78, R65, B109)
 'GOSContainer Class' 'Gos Container' 'Gos ContainerGOSContainer Class' ()
Shell Window Class - 'Control  Container'   (L24, T82, R65, B104)
 'Control  Container6' 'Control  ContainerShell Window Class6' 'Shell Window Class6' ()
ATL:664AB3D8 - ''   (L24, T82, R66, B104)
 '40' 'ATL:664AB3D8' ()
SysPager - 'SAPPagerForToolbar'   (L24, T82, R95, B104)
 'Pager' 'SAPPagerForToolbar' 'SAPPagerForToolbarPager' ()
ToolbarWindow32 - ''   (L24, T82, R95, B104)
 '41' 'Toolbar' ()
```

control need is Afx:62F20000:8:00010003:00000010:00000000 but its  getting changed for every run.when inspected with swapy,controlID is same.Is there a possiblity using controlID Text on this control can be retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Control ID is usually not guaranteed to be permanent. I believe matching `class_name` by regular expression would be more reliable.

```
app.Dialog.child_window(class_name_re='^constant_part.*$').some_method()

# though Control ID can be used so
app.Dialog.child_window(control_id=0x5D).some_method()
# or
app.Dialog.child_window(class_name_re='^constant_part.*$', found_index=0).some_method()
```

The same should work for `title_re`. In your particular case:

```
sapfrontednsession.child_window(title_re='^Standard PO created under the number \d+$').click()
```

Control ID can be found using Spy++ utility included into MS Visual Studio (available from Start menu).

```
sapfrontednsession.child_window(control_id=<found ID in hex>).click()
```

Comment: Vasily thank you for your reply.code you mentioned is for only windows or controls within it to.Unable to get text from control because its class name is changing for every run.

Comment: It's for controls inside the dialog. Of course, dialog specification could be changed with your window title as well. Will add to the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs.Helped in  Text comparision to retrieve output :  sapfrontendsession['^Standard PO created under the number \d+$'].Texts()[0]

Answer (score 0):

Through my research into this topic it sounds like getting text from an afx control is devastatingly complex as this text is directly drawn to the screen (it's an image) unlike other, for example 'static', controls.

I'd say your best bet is to use the MSAA or UI Automation framework to navigate over the application's UI structure from the main window.

Comment: pywinauto 0.6.0+ already supports UI Automation under the hood. :) Just use `Application(backend="uia")`. The rest methodology is pretty the same.